# Excel VBA loop through intersections of pivot items and pivot field

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to write a code that can apply conditional formatting to each intersection of two pivot fields separately.  For example, I would like to select all entries for PartNumber `541-9037-100` in the "Average of TransA1" column, apply conditional formatting, then proceed to PartNumber, select all entries in the "Average of TransA1" column, apply conditional formatting, etc.

PartNumbers will vary from week to week, so I am looking for a generic code that will loop through every item in the PartNumber field.

I have tried to use a for loop, but seem to be selecting the entire Average of TransA1 column at once rather than the intersection of the Average of TransA1 column and each PartNumber item.  A copy of my code is below- Can anyone help me revise my code to select only the intersections of the fields?

ConditionalFormatting2 Macro

```
'
' Select intersect of pivot table and output cell values to apply formatting
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

For Each PivotItem In pt.PivotFields("PartNumber").PivotItems
'Select the "Average of TransA1" column and apply conditional formatting
    Application.PivotTableSelection = True
    pt.PivotSelect "Average of TransA1", xlDataOnly
  With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
  End With
  Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
  Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
    .Rank = 30
    .Percent = True
  End With
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
  End With
  Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
  Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
  Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
    .Rank = 10
    .Percent = True
  End With
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 8420607
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
  Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
  Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Bottom
    .Rank = 30
    .Percent = True
  End With
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
  End With
  Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
  Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
  Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Bottom
    .Rank = 10
    .Percent = True
  End With
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 8420607
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Next PivotItem

'
End Sub
```

strong text

Comment: For now I got rid of the conditional formating and am only highlighting the cells yellow to reduce complexity.  This is a little closer to what I am looking for, but it selects each cell in the Average of TransA1 column individually whereas I want to select all cells in that column with the same PartNumber value at once.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out- it isn't pretty, but it works

```
'declare variables
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim pn As String
Dim rw As Integer
Dim cntpi As Long

'Sets current worksheet, initializes rw and cntpi
Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
rw = 5
cntpi = 0

'sets rng1 as the Average of TransA1 column
Range("A5").Select
Set rng1 = pt.PivotFields("Average of TransA1").DataRange.EntireColumn

'Loops through each part number, applies conditional formatting to all part number groups in data area
For Each PivotItem In pt.PivotFields("PartNumber").PivotItems
    rw = rw + cntpi
    Range(Cells(rw, 1), Cells(rw, 1)).Select
    pn = Trim(ActiveCell.Value)
    Set rng2 = pt.PivotFields("PartNumber").PivotItems(pn).DataRange.EntireRow
    Intersect(rng1, rng2).Select
    cntpi = Selection.Rows.Count

    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 6737151
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 6736896
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 6737151
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With


Next PivotItem
```